# Eclipse Renamed my EAR to snapshot, how can i correct it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I wanted to enable Maven in eclipse, I downloaded the software and selected "configure->convert to maven project" on my EAR.  I am new to Maven and after looking over the options and reading some documentation I had a change of heart.  I'll deal with this later I thought.

So I selected "Maven->disable Maven" and i thought this would take care of it.  Maven was disabled however now my EAR is being described by the WAS Liberty server as EAR_Name (EAR_Name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

In addition basically all hell broke loose with the WAR i have included.  The WAR works fine on its own so I am just trying to figure out what changed and how I can correct it.  It may be likely that the EAR no longer working has nothing to do with the Maven reversion but I'd like to correct it nonetheless.

Comment: Just remove the project and import it again as normal Eclipse if you want to get rid of the maven changes. It will really be faster and more reliable than reversing all by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out by deleting the settings folder and restoring from source code control I was able to get rid of the WebServer's insistence on the naming convention.  So if anyone's curious, delete (and restore) or modify the .settings folder files

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a pom.xml file in your project. That's what Maven uses to build your application. You might have a section (probably at the beginning) that indicates the project's version, name, etc. If you're not using maven, you might want to remove that pom.xml file just in case.

Comment: Well, I gave that a shot with no luck.  The POM file did have it named with the snapshot suffix, but when I deleted it, eclipse still sees it that way, even after rebooting it.  Also tried add/remove the project.  At any rate I created a different EAR and that works fine for the interim.  Still, the subtleties of Eclipse continue to elude ... Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: you might have to build it again with maven, if that's the problem. mvn clean:install and maybe even mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse (to create the eclipse project).